# In Typescript, why function overloading order matters only when the overloaded function is passed as a parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

When a function is overloaded and passed to a function as parameter, it seems to not maintain the overloading, only the last definition is chosen.

I verified that the definition order matters and created a minimal example: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-2CghBiFxwDgL4fvOfgKFiBuCQgGuEYiBgSggHDKMpJflet4loMcAgE4cDnKMP5PvyHAAR+X4YY+fIvsCIhAUgbhgRBGBwJEeCkJYED2I4SheHGiRnJKpqkPWzotv28EACqgZQYEgA+YBfIgmFEYCb4oGQ4GUJEX7rDAEmILRGCWJx0q1s6h74sIEZ7KegnCYpiBiWpknSX+goiPJnhgcpSiqepmloNpJq6UZaQmQEQA)

```
function call<U extends object, V>(method: Api<U, V>, params: U): Promise<V> {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        method(params, (err, resp) => {
            return resp;
        })
    });
}

type Api<U, V> = (params: U, callback: (err: {}, resp: V) => void) => void;

/** Signature (1) */
function apiMethod(params: {id: number}, callback: (err: {}, resp: {lol: number}) => void): void;
/** Signature (2) */
function apiMethod(callback: (err: {}, resp: {lol: number}) => void): void;
function apiMethod(
    paramsOrCallback: {id: number} | ((err: {}, resp: {lol: number}) => void), 
    callback?: (err: {}, resp: {lol: number}) => void
) {
    if (callback) {
        callback({}, {lol: 1234567});
    }
    if (typeof paramsOrCallback === 'function') {
        paramsOrCallback({}, {lol: 1234567});
    }
}

// If signature (1) before signature (2) then this is a type error
// If you move signature (2) before signature (1) then this is allowed
const r = call(apiMethod, {id: 3});

// This is using signature (1) and is working well
apiMethod({id: 123}, () => {});
// This is using signature (2) and is working well
apiMethod(() => {});
```

I was expecting this example to compile and work correctly independently of the order of signature (1) and signature (2).

Seems that the TS compiler decides which function definition at the time in which the function is passed and for some reason the last definition is always chosen.

I would like to have clarification about why this is happening (and suggested reading material about internals of function overloading) and how to remediate enriching the type of the function `call` in order to make it work independently of the signature (1) and (2) order.

Comment: Relevant [GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30369#issuecomment-476402214)

Comment: There are [relevant GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29312) but I don't know if any of them are really useful as reading material ("it's too hard to do overload resolution during type parameter inference; we just pick the last one... or maybe the first one").  If you think this counts as an answer I'll turn it into one.

Comment: The issue is a bit frustrating to me because I'd like to write something that turns an overloaded function type into a tuple of non-overloaded function types, which you could use to fix `call()` or possibly `apiMethod`, but there are [limitations that make this difficult](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28867).

Comment: Also, you might consider using [unions of argument tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgRlAvFAFBATugXFA3gXwBop0IBnMHXKAGwHsacA7AVwFs4Mp8BKJAPigA3OgEsAJgG4AUADMWTAMbBRdJlACGYUQFkIwABZ1xKaVCgA6KwG0wG9BrZkA8uhgaaNOBsUBrYooeXj6+ALo41tQSzOyc6NzE8KFQAD5Q1knSPDgiEnhmUKKyqIGe3n58uAXmpcF+KATE1PSMUACMAEwAzAAsAKwAbADs3Dwy5vgFRaigkHTFdg5Oru5lIUiIyABE8koqaluV1VCLji5uQeW+DUR4tAw4nb2DI7zj3NKTQA) instead of overloads; they behave similarly but the inference works.  Let me know if this meets your needs and I'll elaborate in an answer.  Otherwise, good luck!!

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz for the answer, the linked material helps us understanding that we should not rely on TS compiler to infer the correct type of the overloaded function if we're passing it around as parameter to another function. It will be interesting to know if the limitation will be addressed in a future release of TS.